# Does PrintWriter object writes directly to the browser?

Tags: java, performance, servlets, browser

We are using `Printwriter` object to print html output on browser. One thing I know about `printwriter` is whenever `out` object called, it writes content to the response. Here I've called `out` objects 8 times. Each time does it writes on browser(means it prints on browser 8 times) or the entire response is printed only once?

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println("<html>");
out.println("<head>");
out.println("<title>TestCase</title>");
out.println("</head>");
out.println("<body>");
out.println("<h2> hai</h2>");
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
```

Comment: Did you try flush ?

Comment: @Anandhakrishnan No. Here I dint use flush() method. In the above written code how many times the response will be printed on the browser. That is my exact question.

Comment: It depends partially on how the `PrintWriter` was created, which you can't see, and what it is wrapped around, ditto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entire response will be flushed only once from the server.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answer. But can you please provide me a reference for this statement.

Comment: Means I want more clarification

Comment: Even I dint use flush method, if I create Printwriter object with response.getWriter(), the entire response is written at a time(once) on the browser

Answer (score 0):

Even I dint use flush method, if I create Printwriter object with response.getWriter(), the entire response is written at a time(once) on the browser